# Telerik RadDropDownTree binding takes a lot of time

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to bind about 24000 rows to a Telerik RadDropDownTree. Currently, the DataBind method takes approximately **3.5 MINUTES** to bind, which is insanely high and definitely a deal breaker. How can I improve the performance and make the binding time as less as possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Showing 24000 rows in a web page is not recommended as this will hang the browser. Try use paging.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dropdowntree/examples/populatingwithdata/webserviceandclienttemplates/defaultcs.aspx

Binding the control to a web service is the answer to your problem.